# Should I block on close method of an asynchronous AutoClosable resource in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an async-resource, I would like to make it auto-closable.  My  resource spins-off a thread and polls an internal reader.

Should I block on close method until the internal resource is closed or is it ok.

My code is something like this...

```
public class MyReader implements AutoClosable {
   ActualReader readerImpl = ...;

   public void close() {
     shutdownRequested.set(true);
   }

   public void start() {
     while(!shutdownRequested) { 
       int someInt = readerImpl.poll(100); 
     }

     readerImpl.close()
   }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, yes, it should block.  close() shouldn't return until and unless everything is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Your resource is supposed to be asynchronous. The method should therefore not block.

Comment: This is what I'm doing currently, but @morido is making a good argument, any thoughts?

Comment: `AutoCloseable` doesn't specify blocking semantics. @morido states himself that there is no obligation to throw any exception, which appears to void his rationale completely. But really your design is at fault. Both your methods should deliver `Futures` which can be interrogated later, or have asynchronous callbacks, or both. See `AsynchronousSocketChannel` for an example.

Comment: interesting - my actual implementation for start takes a callback.  Just want to make sure I understand - how can i return a future from the close method i'm overriding AutoClosable?

Comment: Hmm, you can't, of course ... I note that [`AsynchronousChannel.close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannel.html#close()) does complete all operations, so maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: ... but OTOH socket closes themselves are asynchronous, unless you've set a positive linger timeout, so that doesn't really prove anything.

Comment: The socket behavior is probably just a leftover from C which does not know about Exceptions and resorts to awkward `errno`s instead. So: I wouldn't consider this exemplary by Java's standards.

Comment: @morido Not clear what you mean. *Of course* Java uses the C socket API, as does everything else under the hood, but in any case what you have here is an asynchronous interface to an operation that is already asynchronous. What exactly isn't 'exemplary' about that?

Answer (score 1):

Ẃhile there may be justifiable exceptions to this rule, I would say that *in general* you should block on `close()`.

**Rationale:** AutoCloseable's [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close%28%29) suggests to throw a generic Exception. Although there is no obligation to throw such an Exception (right now you are not doing it), you are essentially prohibiting yourself from ever changing this in the future. By making the internal logic of `close()` asynchronous you cannot really pass on any misbehavior that may occur while closing your resource.

Comment: No. Asynchronous methods should not block, by definition.